# Make line height consistent across different fonts

Tags: css, fonts

I have syntax highlighting code that produces a mix of fixed and sans-serif fonts.

The problem is that these have different heights:

```css
.wrapper {
  float: left;
  border-bottom: 1px solid red;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
}

.delim {
  font-family: Courier, fixed;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <span class="delim">{</span>
  Content A
  <span class="delim">}</span>
</div>

<div class="wrapper">
  Content B
</div>
```

Depending on your fonts you should see something like this:

[image: Problem screenshot]

I want *A* and *B* to line up so that the red line appears to be continuous.

Note that I am **not asking how to line up the bottom of the outer boxes**, that's just so there's an easily demoable snippet - my underlying issue is that the height changes when the fixed width font content is added.

How do I keep it consistent so that the height of the line doesn't change as characters are added to it in different fonts?

Comment: are all fonts the same size?

Comment: I don't think you can... *sans* javascript and then it might be problematic...but that's outside my area of expertise

Answer (score 2):

You can set line-height on both so that it stays even. I added padding on the initial container just to give it some breathing room.

https://jsfiddle.net/6frqxrf4/

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <span class="delim">{</span>
  Content A
  <span class="delim">}</span>
</div>

<div class="wrapper">
  Content B
</div>

<div class="wrapper">
  <span class="delim-a">{</span>
  Content C
  <span class="delim-a">}</span>
</div>

.wrapper {
  float: left;
  border-bottom: 1px solid red;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  line-height: 12px;
  padding-bottom: 3px;
}

.delim {
  font-family: Courier, fixed;
  line-height: 4px;
}

.delim-a{
  font-family: Palatino;
  line-height: 4px;
}
```

Comment: Cheers, that works, but it's rather cludgy: the relative heights of the lines/fonts are a little unpredictable too - `12px` vs `4px` works for Arial vs Courier, but resulted in subpixel differences for similar fonts on alternate devices.

Answer (score 0):

Just add to your `.delim` class `line-height: 0px;`